# In OCaml, how can I create an out_channel which writes to a string/buffer instead of a file on disk

Tags: io, ocaml

I have a function of type `in_channel -> out_channel -> unit` which will output something to an `out_channel`. Now I'd like to get its output as a string. Creating temporary files to write and read it back seems ugly, so how can I do that? Is there any other methods to create `out_channel` besides `Pervasives.open_out` family?

Actually, this function implemented a repl. What I really need is to test it programmatically, so I'd like to first wrap it to a function of type `string -> string`. For creating the `in_channel`, it seems I can use `Scanf.Scanning.from_string`, but I don't know how to create the `out_channel` parameter.

Comment: I don't think there's a way to do this. It would be tricky, because strings have a fixed length in OCaml. They're not really suitable as an expandable place to store characters. You can use Printf.sprintf to create a string with the same contents that Printf.fprintf would write to an output channel.  But other than that, you might have to build your own mechanism.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OCaml Batteries Included has `output_string` and `output_buffer` functions in its `BatIO` module which seem to do what you want: http://ocaml-batteries-team.github.com/batteries-included/hdoc/BatIO.html

It might require you to use their input/output types.

Comment: for futur readers, this is now located in the BatBuffer library : http://ocaml-batteries-team.github.io/batteries-included/hdoc2/BatBuffer.html

Answer (score 4):

If you don't mind your tests relying on the `Unix` module, then you can use `Unix.pipe` to create a file descriptor pair, create an `in_channel` from the readable side, an `out_channel` from the writable side, and then write the string to the writable side and pass the `in_channel` to the code under test.

> ```
> val pipe : unit -> file_descr * file_descr
> ```
>
> Create  a  pipe.  The first component of the result is opened for
>   reading, that's the exit to the pipe.  The  second  component  is
>   opened for writing, that's the entrance to the pipe.
>
> ```
> val in_channel_of_descr : file_descr -> Pervasives.in_channel
> ```
>
> Create  an  input channel reading from the given descriptor.  The
>   channel is initially in binary mode;  use  set_binary_mode_in  ic
>   false if text mode is desired.
>
> ```
> val out_channel_of_descr : file_descr -> Pervasives.out_channel
> ```
>
> Create  an  output  channel writing on the given descriptor.  The
>   channel is initially in binary mode; use  set_binary_mode_out  oc
>   false if text mode is desired.

Unix pipes are a bit heavy-weight for anything with high throughput, but they should be fine for a test-harness.